# sam cli debugging vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, aws-toolkit

i try debug a lambda with aws toolkit for vscode, but i have this error

Unable to communicate with the Python Debug Adapter. The debugger might not succeed when attaching to your SAM Application.
Attaching debugger to SAM Application...
Unable to attach Debugger. Check the Terminal tab for output. If it took longer than expected to successfully start, you may still attach to it.

this is my launch on vscode, but the toolkit don't use

```
{
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
                        {
               "name": "SAM CLI Python Hello World",
               "type": "python",
               "request": "attach",
               "port": 3001,
               "host": "0.0.0.0",
               "pathMappings": [
                   {
                       "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/NewDocument/build",
                       "remoteRoot": "/var/task"
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
     }
```